# Deduping the SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a table with almost 1 million rows and has a lot of duplicate data in it which I'd like to delete from it. I was wondering how to do that exactly?

The table columns are: User Name, Specialization, dob, address, city, state, zip, and telephone. I don't have a any unique ID in the table.

There could be similar names, addresses across the rows in the table. I have to identify all those similar matches and remove the duplicates.

Sample data:

```
Name              Specialisation     DOB        Address       Country
Alexande Loord    Arts               7/2/1993   #25, Fairfax    US
Alexander L       Arts               7/2/1993   #25,Fairfax,VA  US
```

In the above case both the records are the same but only the name is in different form. I have identify such cases and improve my data quality by having maximum possible information for each user by removing the duplicates.

How can I dedupe this and leave 1 unique entry (row) within the table for each user?

Thank you all in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way is to truncate the table and re-populate it.  If you have no unique key, then you don't have an identity column so the following should work:

```
select distinct t.*
into temp_t
from t;

truncate table t;

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_t;
```

Notes:

- This is one of the few cases where I use `insert` without a list of columns -- the columns are chosen from the table.
- I would advise you to add a unique identity column to the table after it is truncated:

  alter table t add tId int identity primary key;
- Always validate the data and backup the table (copy the contents) before doing such an operation.

Comment: solution works for duplicates but the question is about similars. A third party tool might be appropriate in this case.